# What LINQ to EF would cause "This operation cannot be performed on an ObjectStateEntry when the object is detached"

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

here is the scenario:

1. MSSQL Database
2. 4 Windows Services talking to MSSQL Database using EF 4.1 DBContext
3. MS Unity for Dependency Injection of the DBContext (not using singleton)
4. I am not explicitly 'detaching' any entities.  Here is the error i'm getting when calling SaveChanges():

   **This operation cannot be performed on an ObjectStateEntry when the object is detached**

I need clues on where to start looking.  Tx in advance!

Comment: Look at the code *before* SaveChanges.

Comment: Stack trace would probably be useful...